# Ethereum DAPP - understanding

Tags: ethereum

I began to understand how to develop smart contracts on the `Ethereum blockchain` and how to write a `web-script` for interacting with a smart contract (buying, selling, statistics ...) And I came to the conclusion what to do. I wanted to know if I understood everything correctly.

1. We write the contract on `http://remix.ethereum.org`, check whether
   all functions work correctly.
2. We are raising `TRUFFLE + GANACHE` to test a contract on our own
   private blockchain.
3. We write a simple `front-end` to interact with the contract, we will
   do everything through Metamask.
4. Deploy everything into the `Ropsten Ethereum test network` and test
   everything there.
5. After successful testing in the test network, we fill everything
   into the main blockchain of Ethereum.

Did I understand everything correctly, and did I take the right steps?

Answer (score 2):

The steps you outlined look good. I would actually say that you don't need to do the first step, as you can use truffle during all steps of the development process.

1. Create a new Truffle project (`truffle init`) and write the smart contracts and migration scripts.
2. Write thorough unit tests using JavaScript (and/or Solidity) and run these tests on a local Ganache instance (`truffle test`). My library [`truffle-assertions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-assertions) can be used to assist in writing these unit tests.
3. Write a frontend to the contract which uses the artefacts generated by Truffle (`truffle compile` and `truffle migrate`). This frontend can be manually tested in the browser with Metamask.
4. Add connection configuration to the `truffle.js` file to connect with Ethereum Testnets (Rinkeby, Kovan, Ropsten) and Mainnet through `truffle-hdwallet-provider` and Infura, so the contracts can be deployed to these networks. [Further explanation](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider).
5. Deploy to a testnet of choice (`truffle migrate --network ropsten`) and do more testing as in step 3.
6. After you've thoroughly tested all functionality across the multiple development steps, deploy to the mainnet (`truffle migrate --network mainnet`).

Of course most of these steps can still be completed without Truffle, but Truffle really simplifies a big part of the process, and there is a lot of documentation/resources available for it.